# How do I avoid repeating this subquery for the IN clause?

Tags: sql, subquery, dry, in-clause

I have an SQL script (currently running against SQLite, but it should probably work against any DB engine) that uses the same subquery twice, and since it might be fetching a lot of records (the table has a couple of million rows) I'd like to only call it once.

A shortened pseudo-version of the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ([the subquery, returns a column of ids]) AS sq
[a couple of joins, that fetches things from other tables based on the ids]
WHERE thisorthat NOT IN ([the subquery again])
```

I tried just using the name (`sq`) in various ways (with/without parenthesis, with/without naming the column of sq etc) but to no avail.

Do I really *have* to repeat this subquery?

**Clarification:**
I am doing this in python and sqlite as a small demo of what *can* be done, but I would like my solution to scale as well as possible with as little modification as possible. In the real situation, the database will have a couple of million rows, but in my example there is just 10 rows with dummy data. Thus, code that *would be well optimized on for example MySQL* is absolutely good enough - it doesn't have to be optimized *specifically for SQLite*. But as I said, the less modification needed, the better.

Comment: I can't speak for SQLite, but most decent RDBMS's should be able to optimize this anyway. For some products (e.g. SQL Server, postgreSQL, etc), you can ensure the text only appears once by using common table expressions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Given that SQLlite is an embeded database that should be small on one hand and does not need to support complex, long running OLAP type queries, a heavy weight optimizer would not really be worth the increase in code and running-time increase for short ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a `WITH` clause in standard SQL, however, I don't know if it is supported by SQLlite - though of course worth a try:

```
WITH mySubQuery AS
(
  [the subquery code]
)

SELECT * FROM
    mySubQuery AS sq
    [a couple of joins, that fetches things from other tables based on the ids]
WHERE thisorthat NOT IN (mySubQuery)
```

That said, what you do here will likely be horribly slow for any data set that is more than a few thousand rows, so I'd try to remodel it if possible - `NOT IN` should be avoided in general, especially if you also have a couple of joins.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but WITH is unfortunately not supported in SQLite.

Comment: As for the performance: What I'm trying to do is join one table to itself via a relations table, and filter on a couple of constraints, and then do the same join again. The constraints will filter out perhaps a couple of hundred rows in the subquery, so there will probably not be a million rows in the actual joins =)

Comment: I still don't really understand why you would need to select from subQuery and then do a not in on the same subquery, can't picture how that would be needed. Can you post the whole SQL, would be really interested to see if it cant be optimized.

Comment: I might post the entire code, and real background info, in a while. However, as for now I don't want to give away too much of the actual problem, since I am supposed to solve it myself.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need a subquery? You could probably rewrite using an `OUTER JOIN` e.g. something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [the subquery's FROM clause] AS sq
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN [a couple of tables based on the ids]
          ON thisorthat = sq.[a column of ids]
 WHERE sq.[a column of ids] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, I question the need to eliminate the duplication. The SQL compiler can see that two subqueries are identical and chose to only do them once if that seems optimal.

In addition, by leaving duplicates in the source, the SQL compiler and optimizer is given the opportunity to treat them differently. For example the subquery flattening optimization of SQLite might be applied to one of a pair of duplicates or applied differently to each. See section 9.0, Subquery flattening of https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the SELECT part into a View than you can filter the View results using the alias "sq"