# Multiple INNER JOIN subqueries sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, inner-join

I have the below query which comes from this post [count number of items in a row in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192205/count-number-of-items-in-a-row-in-mysql) which counts how many times in a row a student has been present/absent from a class.

```
    SELECT
        classlist.studentid,
        student.name,
        classStatus.name status,
        COUNT(*) presentcnt
    FROM
        classlist 
        INNER JOIN student ON classlist.studentid=student.id
        INNER JOIN classstatus ON classlist.presentid=classstatus.id
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                studentid,
                max(CASE WHEN presentid=0 THEN id END)  max_0,
                max(CASE WHEN presentid=1 THEN id END)  max_1
            FROM classlist
            GROUP BY studentid
        ) s
        ON coalesce(classlist.id>least(max_0,max_1) AND classlist.id<=greatest(max_0,max_1),1) AND s.studentid=classlist.studentid
    GROUP BY classlist.studentid
```

This works as expected,

```
    STUDENTID   NAME    STATUS  PRESENTCNT
    111         John    Present     1
    222         Kate    Absent      2
    333         Matt    Present     5
```

I want to extend the query so that I have a column showing if the student particpated in the class.

If I run an independent query I get the results I want

```
    SELECT
        classlist.studentid,
        student.name,
        participatedStatus.name status,
        COUNT(*) participatedcnt
    FROM
        classlist 
        INNER JOIN student ON classlist.studentid=student.id
        INNER JOIN participatedStatus ON classlist.participatedid=participatedStatus.id
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                studentid,
                max(CASE WHEN participatedid=0 THEN id END)  max_0,
                max(CASE WHEN participatedid=1 THEN id END)  max_1
            FROM classlist
            group by studentid
        ) s
        ON coalesce(classlist.id>least(max_0,max_1) 
        AND classlist.id<=greatest(max_0,max_1),1)
        AND s.studentid=classlist.studentid
    group by classlist.studentid

    STUDENTID   NAME    STATUS  PARTICIPATEDCNT
    111         John    Yes     1
    222         Kate    No      2
    333         Matt    Yes     2
```

However I want to merge them into the one query so I get

```
    STUDENTID   NAME    STATUS  PRESENTCNT  STATUS2     PARTICIPATEDCNT
    111         John    Present     1       Yes         1
    222         Kate    Absent      2       No          2
    333         Matt    Present     5       Yes         2
```

I am confused about how this can be achieved as I am selecting count *, how can I acheive this?

A sample of the data I am using is in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f883c/1) and below

```
    CREATE TABLE classlist
        (`id` int, `studentid` int, `subjectid` int, `presentid` int, `participatedid` int);

    CREATE TABLE student
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4));

    CREATE TABLE subject
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4));

    CREATE TABLE classStatus
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(8));

    CREATE TABLE participatedStatus
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(8));

    INSERT INTO classlist   (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `presentid`, `participatedid`)
    VALUES  (1, 111, 1, 1, 0),  (2, 222, 3, 0, 0),  (3, 333, 2, 1, 0),  (4, 111, 4, 0, 0),  (5, 111, 1, 1, 0),  (6, 222, 3, 0, 0),  (7, 333, 2, 1, 1),  (8, 111, 4, 0, 0),  (9, 111, 4, 0, 0),  (10, 111, 4, 0, 0), (11, 111, 1, 1, 1), (12, 333, 3, 1, 0), (13, 333, 2, 1, 1), (14, 333, 3, 1, 1);

    INSERT INTO student (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES  (111, 'John'),(222, 'Kate'),(333, 'Matt');

    INSERT INTO subject (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES  (1, 'MATH'),(2, 'ENG'),(3, 'SCI'),(4, 'GEO');

    INSERT INTO classStatus (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES  (0, 'Absent'),  (1, 'Present');

    INSERT INTO participatedStatus  (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES  (0, 'No'),(1, 'Yes');
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Do you want to know the number of consecutive classes for which a student was BOTH present AND attentive? So, for instance, if a student attended 5 consecutive classes but was inattentive during the 4th class, that would register as '3,1' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
        studid,
        studname,
        status,
        presentcnt,
        status1,
        participatedcnt FROM
(SELECT
        classlist.studentid studid,
        student.name studname,
        classStatus.name status,
        COUNT(*) presentcnt
    FROM
        classlist 
        INNER JOIN student ON classlist.studentid=student.id
        INNER JOIN classstatus ON classlist.presentid=classstatus.id
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                studentid,
                max(CASE WHEN presentid=0 THEN id END)  max_0,
                max(CASE WHEN presentid=1 THEN id END)  max_1
            FROM classlist
            GROUP BY studentid
        ) s
        ON coalesce(classlist.id>least(max_0,max_1) AND classlist.id<=greatest(max_0,max_1),1) AND s.studentid=classlist.studentid
    GROUP BY classlist.studentid)x
JOIN

(SELECT
        classlist.studentid,
        student.name,
        participatedStatus.name status1,
        COUNT(*) participatedcnt
    FROM
        classlist 
        INNER JOIN student ON classlist.studentid=student.id
        INNER JOIN participatedStatus ON classlist.participatedid=participatedStatus.id
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                studentid,
                max(CASE WHEN participatedid=0 THEN id END)  max_0,
                max(CASE WHEN participatedid=1 THEN id END)  max_1
            FROM classlist
            group by studentid
        ) s
        ON coalesce(classlist.id>least(max_0,max_1) 
        AND classlist.id<=greatest(max_0,max_1),1)
        AND s.studentid=classlist.studentid
    group by classlist.studentid)y
ON x.studid=y.studentid
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f883c/13)

Comment: (1) Both tables `s` resulting from the subqueries for the INNER JOINs are exactly the same. So, performance-wise, does the RDBMS somehow manages to optimize this, running it only once and storing the result, or does this subquery runs twice? (2) If it runs twice, does it make sense to somehow store the result of this subquery somewhere, to use it in both places and optimize the query performance? Actually, is there even a way to actually store the `s` table?

Comment: Ok, just found my answer to question (2), in [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5470483/4212870). In summary, it is possible to use the WITH statement to "store" the results of a subquery. Question (1) remains unanswered for now